# Tkinter/Python: Error al borrar un texto de un canvas y querer escribir uno diferente

Tags: python, tkinter

He creado una ventana "main" con un canvas en el que cargo una imagen y una línea de texto a partir de una entrada Entry. Al borrar el texto del canvas y del Entry con la función `canvas.delete(tag_del_texto)` y `entry.delete(0, 'end')` y querer escribir otro me sale el siguiente error:

> command=lambda:texto1(main)) TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

`texto1(main)` es la función para crear el texto, main es el nombre de la ventana.

He buscado información sobre este error, pero los ejemplos se basan en funciones matemáticas y no en objetos.

La parte correspondiente del código es:

```
# Creo el texto donde etxt1 es el nombre del Entry:

def texto1():
    global texto1
    try:
        texto1 = canvas.create_text(cw/2, 30, text=etxt1.get(), anchor=CENTER, font=ft, fill="white", tags="tx1")
    except:
        pass

# Borro el texto con la siguiente función:

def borrar1(main):
    canvas.delete("tx1") # Esto borra el texto del canvas
    etxt1.delete(0, 'end') # Esto borra el texto del Entry
```

Pero al querer escribir de nuevo algo en el Entry y crearlo en el canvas me da el error ya descrito arriba.

He intentado con el método `canvas.delete('all')`, pero sigue dando el mismo error además de que me borra también la imagen y eso no quiero.

Los métodos `update.idletasks()` o `canvas.forget()` tampoco hacen nada en este caso.

Leí que el método `destroy`, en cambio, elimina totalmente el widget y ya no se puede volver a usar.

¿A qué puede deberse el error?

Comment: puedes mostrar la parte del código donde esta command=lambda:texto1(main)), una posible razon es que no es recomendable llamar a las variables y funciones con el mismo nombre: def texto1(): y global texto

Comment: Tienes razón, no me había dado cuenta. Cambié los nombres y se solucionó. Gracias

Comment: pondré eso en la solución y por favor marcala como correcta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

una posible razon es que no es recomendable llamar a las variables y funciones con el mismo nombre, por ejemplo tú utilizas:

```
def texto1(): 
    global texto1
```